# PostGIS view has missing features

Tags: postgis, geoserver

I have created a SQL view from a large MultiPolygon table, and am attempting to serve it as a WFS layer via Geoserver.

While testing the layer, I've noticed that some of the features are missing. This is evident when loading the WFS layer, or also doing a SQL query on the view for the missing features (the query returns no results).

I've added 2 screenshots showing the original layer (grey polygons), and the view layer with missing features (orange polygons).
[image: original layer]

[image: view]

Has anyone come across a similar issue, and a fix?

**UPDATE**

The source table `table_a` has a `geom` field as `geometry(MULTIPOLYGON, 4326)`. It contains about 3 million records

The view queries `table_a`, and does a spatial join on a couple of other tables as well, like so:

```
SELECT
    a.feature_id,
    a.geom,
    a.name,
    b.label,
    c.name
FROM table_a AS a
    JOIN admin_boundaries AS b ON st_intersects(a.geom, b.geom)
    JOIN places AS c ON st_intersects(a.geom, c.geom);
```

I'm not using `maxFeatures` in my query, and Geoserver is set to `maxFeatures = 0`

**SOLVED**

As suggested by @alpha-beta-soup I was using a series of `INNER JOINs`, and some of my features weren't intersecting, so they were missing. Switching to `LEFT JOINs` solved the issue.

Comment: Please **edit** the question to provide more information about the table and the view definition.

Comment: Is the serving as WFS aspect relevant here?  If an SQL query cannot find the features then I am thinking that your WFS is just respecting the SQL result.

Comment: Are you using `maxFeatures` in your WFS request? (`count` in WFS 2.0.0)

Comment: @PolyGeo yes you may be onto something, about it not being Geoserver's fault. I've been considering that as well, though it's confusing that a completely-standard view would drop features (implying that PostGIS views themselves are buggy)

Comment: There's no way a routine SQL query is "buggy". Are you sure your features intersect? Try pull one of the offending features out individually and test the spatial intersection.

Comment: Please consider adding your edit as an answer so this question can be considered resolved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your features do not properly intersect; using a series of `JOIN` statements in the definition of your view meant that not all features of your `table_a` table were retained in the final view. Using `LEFT JOIN` ensures that non-matching (i.e. non-intersecting) records are retained.