# Calculating point layer values within polygon features in QGIS 2

Tags: qgis-2, point-in-polygon, aggregation, virtual-layer

There are two layers

- polygon `'BereichBerechnung'` with a field `"Are_Number"`
- points `'EW2017'` with a field `"EWjeAdr"`

[image: Example_of_data]

In QGIS with a Virtual Layer, I want to calculate the sum of the field `"EWjeAdr"` for points that are within each feature from the layer `'BereichBerechnung'`.

I have found [Updating field to give count of points in polygon using STIntersects?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44526) which seems related but I cannot figure out how to adjust my expression properly.

With this code:

```sql
SELECT Are_Number, SUM(EWjeAdr)
FROM BereichBerechnung
JOIN EW_Data ON BereichBerechnung.ogr_geometry.STContains(EW2017.ogr_geometry) = 1;
GROUP BY Are_Number
```

I am getting the following error:

[image: Error]

How can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a bit of luck and suggestions from @Kazuhito, I ended up with

```sql
SELECT ST_UNION(B.geometry), B."Are_Number", SUM(D."EWjeAdr")
FROM "BereichBerechnung" AS B
JOIN "EW_Data" AS D ON contains(B.geometry, D.geometry)
GROUP BY B."Are_Number"
```

In case if there is a necessity to preserve geometries for which there are no overlaps between polygons and points in other words `contains(B.geometry, D.geometry)` command gives `NULL` use [`LEFT JOIN`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) which will do the trick.

```sql
SELECT ST_UNION(B.geometry), B."Are_Number", SUM(D."EWjeAdr")
FROM "BereichBerechnung" AS B
LEFT JOIN "EW_Data" AS D ON contains(B.geometry, D.geometry)
GROUP BY B."Are_Number"
```

---

**References:**

- [PostGIS view has missing features](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/173673/postgis-view-has-missing-features)
- [SpatiaLite SQL functions reference list](https://www.gaia-gis.it/spatialite-2.1/spatialite2_sql.html)

Answer (score 4):

> For QGIS 3

In the Processing Toolbox use the tool ["Join attributes by location (summary)"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#join-attributes-by-location-summary), make sure it's the summary tool and not the other one.

---

> For QGIS 2

In the Processing Toolbox use the tool ["Join attributes by location"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#join-attributes-by-field-value) and change the `Attribute summary` option to *Take summary of intersecting features*.

---

The **Input layer** should be the polygon and the **Join Layer** should be the points.

I created two scratch layers in a project, in the point layer I populated a field with a random number (`"rand_num"`), see the result of the joined polygon here:

[image: Result_of_execution]