# Getting percentage of string values for point layer within polygons of another one

Tags: qgis-3, spatial-statistics, string

I have two layers. One with polygons of areas of a city. Another one - with points corresponding to buildings. In point layer there is a field with the names of management companies of that buildings. I need to calculate the percentage of management companies (unique strings) in each area (polygon).

I tried to use **Join attributes by location (summary)** and **v.vect.stats**, but both wants my attributes to be numerical, not strings. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Intersect the areas and buildings to get them in one attribute table, then use Field Calculator

Comment: Another idea is to: [1] Join points to polygons and then us the [2] [Group Stats](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/GroupStats/) plugin

Comment: IMHO usage of a Virtual layer can be useful, you can find some inspiration in this thread: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/305165/calculating-point-layer-values-within-polygon-features-in-qgis-2

Comment: Is there a field (in point layer) indicating what point is in which polygon?

Comment: @BERA, I can intersect that layers, but I have no idea how to get percentage for companies inside areas with Filed Calculator. Gonna try to google some examples of grouping by value of the field.

Comment: @Taras, Group Stats gives me count of each unique string (company name) but not percentage. Of course it is possible to get CSV file for each area and make some calculations after that, but I'm seeking for automated way...

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz, creating the field you speaking about is not a problem, but that does not helps me. Feel that the solution is somewhere in creating correct expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can calculate the number of points with the same management company within each of the polygons using this expression with the aggregate function `count`, where `company` is the field containing the management company and `polygon` is the name of your polygon layer:

```
count ($id, group_by:= company || array_first(overlay_within('polygon', $id)))
```

It calculates the number of features, grouped by a string concatenated from the company's name and the id of the polygon it lies within. Simply leave away the `company ||` part to get the whole number of points per polygon and thus calculate the percentage using this expression:

```
count (
    $id, 
    group_by:= company || array_first (overlay_within('polygon', $id))
) /
count (
    $id, 
    group_by:= array_first(overlay_within('polygon', $id))
) *100
```

Comment: when I'm trying to create new field for point layer with the first of expressions you suggested QGIS hangs...

Comment: Depending on the number of features, it can indeed take a while. Maybe creating a spatial index can improve speed. To improve efficiency, you could limit the calculation to just one feaure per company per polygon - now, the same calculation is repeated for each feature, even if it is part of the same group (same company in same polygon).

Comment: sorry don't know how to set such a limit. I have about 8700 points. By the way, preview of this expression is working and showing values for different companies...

Comment: Finally it works for the part of my data. After deleting duplicates I'm getting a point layer with percentage for each company.